# Should a class method that returns an instance of the class be an instance or static method?

Tags: php, static, self

In php, say I have

```
class People{
    public function get_person(){
        return self();
    }
}
```

Should this be static so I call it using

```
$person = People::get_person();
```

or member, so I create an instance of People first, like

```
$person = new Person();
$person_two = $person->get_person();
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you want to do that ? isn't `$person_two = $person` good enough ?

Comment: If I call `get_person` in one context, such as the controller of an MVC, then create `$person_two` within `get_person` in the model of the MVC